# ranges on js using Array.prototype.fill()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am really new to JS and some of the very useful functions in the ES6. I am trying to learn more about how to create ranges using fill and I have gotten the following code to work the way I want based on some examples BUT I don't understand how it actually works. When I print out the values of both prevYear and nextYear in the console, I can see that nextYear is increasing by 1 every time and thus making the years increase. That is awesome but, I would like to understand how is nextYear working if I haven't set up any value to it. I tried adding 1 to prevYear and it wouldn't work the right way. Here my code for more clarity :

startYear = 1900
EndYear = 1910

// this code returns =[ 1900, 1901, 1902, 1903, 1904, 1905, 1906, 1907, 1908, 1909, 1910 ]

```
    var yearsRange = Array(endYear - startYear + 1).fill(startYear).map((prevYear,nextYear) => prevYear + nextYear);
```

It will make more sense to me to change this code to :

```
var yearsRange = Array(endYear - startYear + 1).fill(startYear).map((prevYear) => prevYear += 1);
```

// this will return [ 1901, 1901, 1901, 1901, 1901, 1901, 1901, 1901, 1901, 1901, 1901]

WHY?

Comment: try adding `console.log` to the `map`'s callback to see what's going on there.

Comment: I did @georg it shows prevYear value's (1900) and nextYear increasing by 1. MY question is HOW is this happening? How is fill or map working to make nextYear increase by 1 every time.

Comment: What would I use .reduce for @DanielA.White? the var actually works the way I want it. I just want to know why is it working the way it is.

Comment: That's how [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) works. The first argument to the callback is the element (1900 every time in your case) and the second argument is the position in the array, which starts at `0`, then `1`, and so on

Comment: @Monique Do you think, you’re updating a global `prevYear`?

Comment: Thanks @Paulpro, makes total sense! I will now go and read more about how map works!

Comment: The use of `prevYear` variable is confusing, it should be actually `yearOffset` or simply `index` for maximum readability. `Array(end - start + 1).fill(start).map((start,index) => start + index);  
`

Comment: correct @sabithpocker, I just changed it to index. I just didn't know how map worked for the second argument and I assumed it will be just another "year". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are horribly named. `prevYear` and `nextYear` make no sense at all (and of course, adding them together would neither).

```
var yearsRange = Array(endYear - startYear + 1)
  .fill(startYear)
  .map((startYear, index) => startYear + index);
```

Comment: Right @Bergi. I was CONFUSED as where the second parameter was coming from/ doing. That was my motivation to ask so I could understand the second parameter and name it accordingly.   :)

Answer (score 0):

A callback is a function. When you run a function, all of the local variables work independently from each other. If it helps, we can make that callback a named function instead.

```js
let arr = Array(11).fill(1910)

let incrementByOne = (num) => {
  return num += 1
}

console.log(arr.map((num) => incrementByOne(num)))
```

Each time you run `incrimentByOne`, it accepts the values from your array, which is always `1990`.